# Add upload photo or file field to opencard 1.5.X

Tags: opencart, registration

How can I add a custom image or file upload field to opencart customer registration page?
I use opencart as mijoshop (a joomla component).

Answer (score 0):

you can get idea from catalog/product.tpl & catalog/product.php